# Duplicate a specific word page for "N" times

Tags: ms-word, ms-office, vba6

I am new to the world of coding. I am trying to create a macro to duplicate a specific page for "N" a number of times. The code duplicates the entire document, hope someone could help me fix this issue. Thanks in advance.

```
Sub DuplicatePage()
Dim numOfCopies As Integer
Dim pageNumber As Integer
Dim i As Integer
'Ask user to enter the number of times to duplicate the page
numOfCopies = InputBox("Enter the number of copies you want to make:")
'Ask the user to enter the page number to duplicate
pageNumber = InputBox("Enter the page number to duplicate:")
'Activate the document
ActiveDocument.Activate
'Check if the entered page number is valid
If pageNumber > ActiveDocument.ComputeStatistics(wdStatisticPages) Then
    MsgBox "The entered page number is greater than the total number of pages in the document. Please enter a valid page number."
    Exit Sub
End If
'Select the page to be duplicated
ActiveWindow.Selection.GoTo What:=wdGoToPage, Which:=wdGoToAbsolute, Count:=pageNumber
Selection.Extend
Selection.Copy
'Duplicate the selected page for the number of times specified by the user
For i = 1 To numOfCopies
    Selection.InsertBreak Type:=wdPageBreak
    Selection.PasteAndFormat (wdFormatOriginalFormatting)
Next i
```

End Sub

Answer (score 0):

For example:

```
Sub DuplicatePage()
Dim c As Long, p As Long, i As Long, RngSrc As Range, RngTgt As Range
'Ask user to enter the number of times to duplicate the page
c = InputBox("Enter the number of copies you want to make:")
'Ask the user to enter the page number to duplicate
p = InputBox("Enter the page number to duplicate:")
With ActiveDocument
  'Check if the entered page number is valid
  If p > .ComputeStatistics(wdStatisticPages) Then
    MsgBox "The entered page number is greater than the total number of pages in the document. Please enter a valid page number."
    Exit Sub
  End If
  'Select the page to be duplicated
  Set RngSrc = .Range.GoTo(What:=wdGoToPage, Name:=p).GoTo(What:=wdGoToBookmark, Name:="\page")
  With RngSrc
    .Characters.Last.InsertBreak Type:=wdPageBreak
    .MoveEndUntil Chr(12), wdForward
    .End = RngSrc.End + 1
    Set RngTgt = .Duplicate
  End With
End With
'Duplicate the selected page for the number of times specified by the user
For i = 1 To c
    RngTgt.Collapse wdCollapseEnd
    RngTgt.FormattedText = RngSrc.FormattedText
Next i
End Sub
```